# Linear dependence of three vector functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, wronskian

I am trying to determine whether the vector functions

x1 = col(e^x, 2e^x, 3e^x)
x2 = col(2e^2x, 4e^2x, 6e^2x)
x3 = col(3e^3x, 6e^3x, 9e^3x)

are linearly independent over all real numbers x.

My instinct is that they are, but when I pose the question to WolframAlpha, it tells me otherwise, and I think it could be because it is interpreting x as a constant rather than a variable?

I know that when we use x = 0, we obtain 3 equations which effectively tell us only c1 + 2c2 + 3c3 = 0.

However, can we deduce nonzero constants from this fact that also work for all other x? Again, I think not, but Wolfram tells me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Set the linear relation $c_1\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2\mathbf{v}_2 + c_3\mathbf{v}_3= 0$ with

$\mathbf{v}_1 = [e^x \quad 2e^{x} \quad 3e^{x}]^T$, $\quad$ $\mathbf{v}_2 = [2e^{2x} \quad 4e^{2x} \quad 6e^{2x}]^T$, $\quad$ $\mathbf{v}_3 = [3e^{3x} \quad 6e^{3x} \quad 9e^{3x}]^T$.

You will find that the only solution to the linear relation above is the trivial solution, $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.

Hence, the three vector functions $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, $ and $ \mathbf{v}_3$ are linearly independent, provided that $x \neq 0$. If $x$ were zero, one can find by inspection that $\mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{v}_2 - \mathbf{v}_3 = 0$, hence resulting in a nontrivial solution.

[Edit] My apologies, I should have thought about the condition when $x = 0$.

BHP

Comment: Thanks. So if the vectors are linearly independent (only possible constants are trivially 0) for x not equal to 0, do we say that the vectors are linearly independent on (-inf, inf)?

Comment: The vector functions are NOT linearly independent over all real x. All it takes to prove that this is so is to find one exception, which in this case would be x=0.

Comment: According to my textbook, the c's are not allowed to vary with x. Thus, they should be linearly independent?

Comment: The weight c's are just scalars so by definition they should not vary with x. As I explained above, the vectors fail to be linearly independent at x = 0 but you said you wanted to find if they are linearly independent for all real x. Hence, the vectors are NOT linearly independent for all real x.